# Grouping by last day of each month—inefficient running

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to pull month end balances from all accounts a customer has for every month. Here is what I've written. This runs correctly and gives me what I want—but it also runs extremely slowly. How would you recommend speeding it up?

```
SELECT          DISTINCT
                [AccountNo]
                ,SourceDate
                ,[AccountType]
                ,[AccountSub]
                ,[Balance]
FROM            [DW].[dbo].[dwFactAccount] AS fact

WHERE           SourceDate IN (
  SELECT          MAX(SOURCEDATE) 
  FROM            [DW].[dbo].[dwFactAccount] 
  GROUP BY        MONTH(SOURCEDATE), 
                  YEAR (SOURCEDATE)
                )

ORDER BY        SourceDate DESC
```

Comment: In order to assist we really need to see the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a window function:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT
   [AccountNo]
  ,[SourceDate]
  ,[AccountType]
  ,[AccountSub]
  ,[Balance]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
     PARTITION BY accountno, EOMONTH(sourcedate) 
     ORDER BY sourcedate DESC
   ) as rn
 FROM [DW].[dbo].[dwFactAccount]
)x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

The row number will establish an incrementing counter in order of sourcedate descending. The counter will restart from 1 when the month in sourcedate changes (or the account number changes) thanks to the EOMONTH function quantising any date in a given month to be the last date of the month (2020-03-9 12:34:56 becomes 2020-03-31, as do all other datetimes in March). Any similar tactic to quantise to a fixed date in the month would also work such as using `YEAR(sourcedate), MONTH(sourcedate)`

Comment: Hmm, not quite - only returns the last day of the most recent month, I need to see every month end.

Comment: @macintyrejohn Are you sure you're partitioning by accountnumber and EOMONTH?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a dimension table for the date with Date as PK, and your SourceDate in the fact table ref. that date dimension table.

Date dimension table can have month, year, week, is_weekend, is_holiday, etc. columns. You join your fact table with the date dimension table and you can group data using any columns in date table you want.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed. Obviously very new, but this was extremely helpful.

Comment: Date tables are handy for all sorts of things such as tracking public holidays and working days, but working out what month a date belongs do doesn't need one

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute first step should be to view the execution plan for the query and determine *why* the query is slow.

The following explains how to see a graphical execution plan:

[Display an Actual Execution Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15)

The steps to interpreting the plan and optimizing the query are too much for an SO answer, but you should be able to find some good articles on the topic by Googling.  You could also post the plan in an edit to your question and get some real feedback on what steps to take to improve query performance.